# Where is my missing Edge?

Tags: c++, set

I'm trying to use a `std::set` where I will throw a bunch of edges in, and have only the unique ones remain.

An `Edge` is a line between two (integer indexed) nodes.  Edge `(1,2)==(2,1)`, because these edges are undirected.

I'm encountering a puzzling situation though, with this.  At the section marked `//??` in the code below, the behavior is not as I expect.

The results of running this code are to only keep 2 edges, (1,2) and (4,8).  (2,1) is discarded by the set, but **it should not be** unless I activate the commented out `//|| ( A==o.B && B==o.A )` section in `operator==`!  What is happening here?

This `set<Edge>` implementation is leaving me feeling .. edgy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>
using namespace std ;

struct Edge
{
  int A,B ;
  Edge( int iA, int iB ) : A(iA), B(iB) {}
  bool operator==( const Edge & o ) const {
    //??
    return ( A==o.A && B==o.B ) ;//|| ( A==o.B && B==o.A ) ;
  }
  bool operator<( const Edge& o ) const {//MUST BE CONST
    return A < o.A && B < o.B ;
  }
  void print() const { printf( "( %d, %d )", A,B ) ; }
  void compare( const Edge& o ) const {
    print() ;
    if( *this==o ) printf( "==" ) ;
    else printf( "!=" ) ;
    o.print() ;
    puts("");
  }
} ;

int main()
{
  Edge e1( 1, 2 ) ;
  Edge e2( 1, 2 ) ;
  Edge e3( 2, 1 ) ;
  Edge e4( 4, 8 ) ;

  e1.compare( e2 ) ;
  e1.compare( e3 ) ;
  e1.compare( e4 ) ;

  set<Edge> edges ;
  edges.insert( e1 ) ;
  edges.insert( e2 ) ;
  edges.insert( e3 ) ;
  edges.insert( e4 ) ;

  printf( "%d edges\n", edges.size() ) ;
  for( auto edge : edges )
  {
    edge.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Also the `<` must implement this (as it is the relevant operator for the order inside sets).

Comment: Yes, it _will_ in the final implementation, I'm just puzzling over why (2,1) is being left out of the `set` _when that || is commented out_

Comment: Hmm.  Well `(1,2) < (2,1)` is false, and `(2,1) < (1,2)` is also false.

Comment: "Equality" (and thus duplicity in your situation) is determined in std container item comparison when **both** `left < right` **and** `right < left` return *false*. It is therefore important (required, in fact) that your comparator enforce a strict ordering. Consider this when building your `operator <()`. This can be especially problematic when using a complex operator that may be utilizing uninitialized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you change your Edge() constructor to ensure that A and B are always initialized such that `A<=B` (if edges can point back to their originating node) or `A<B` (if not), and forego having the extra logic in the operator== implementation.  That seems less "edgy" to me.

Comment: Wow! Great answer.  I just rewrote the constructor, `A=min(iA,iB); B=max(iA,iB);`.  Bonus points for efficiency!  Of course that means `A` and `B` inside `Edge` objects would need to be protected members, and `set` functions would have to be written, but for my purposes, they were not going to be changed anyway.

Answer (score 5):

C++ set does not care about your `==` operator as much as it does about your `<` operator. It is your `<` operator that presents the problem: if you would like to make sure that `(1,2)` is equal to `(2,1)`, you should change the implementation of your `<` to behave like this:

```
bool operator<( const Edge& o ) const {
    int myMin = min(A, B);
    int myMax = max(A, B);
    int hisMin = min(o.A, o.B);
    int hisMax = max(o.A, o.B);
    return myMin < hisMin || ( myMin == hisMin && myMax < hisMax );
}
```

What this implementation does is constructing a *canonical representation* of an edge, where the smaller of the `{A,B}` becomes the "canonical `A`", and the larger one becomes the "canonical `B`". When edges are compared in their canonical form, the equality of `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` can be *implied* from the fact that both `(1,2) < (2,1)` and `(2,1) < (1,2)` evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your `operator<` is wrong, both `e3<e2` and `e2<e3` are false.

Maybe you wanted something like:

```
return A < o.A || ((A == o.A) && (B < o.B)) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your comparison should be

```
return (A == o.A && B == o.B) || (B == o.A && A == o.B);
```